# Create and save just the instance of a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playfab

I have the following problem:

I am trying to load data from a playfab server and store it on a script in Unity.

```
if (_item.ItemClass == "building")
        {
            string _id = _item.ItemId;

            Debug.Log("loaded building: id: " + _id);

            int _idInt = int.Parse(_id);
            
            BuildingScript _placeholder = new BuildingScript();                             // create the building, that will be added to the players local inventory

            // then translate its custom data:
            
            // _item.CustomData
            
            _placeholder.SO_of_This = GameManager.instance.buildingArray[_idInt];           // add the loaded buildingsList Scriptable Object to the placeholder, to later load the correct model

            Debug.Log("SO_Building of the building we found: " + _placeholder.SO_of_This.name);
            
            buildingsList.Add(_placeholder);                                                    // add the placeholder to the player
        }
```

Everything works, except of the last line, which is adding the newly created script to the corresponding list on the script performing this action.

Is it not possible for unity to just store scripts somewhere without them being attached to gameobjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so without attaching to a **GameObject** but for that to work your **BuildingScript** need to stop inheriting from **MonoBehaviour**.

Current BuildingScript:

```
public class BuildingScript : MonoBehaviour {}
```

New BuildingScript:

```
public class BuildingScript {}
```

**NOTES :**

- You will not be able to use certain classes and methods inside your **BuildingScript** class if you stop inheriting from **MonoBehaviour**. You will also not be able to add your **BuildingScript** to a **GameObject** anymore.
- When creating a class inheriting from **MonoBehaviour** do not create an object like this:

  ```
    BuildingScript _placeholder = new BuildingScript();
  ```
- Instead it is meant to be added to a **GameObject** like this:

  ```
    yourGameObject.AddComponent<BuildingScript>();
  ```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know the MonoBehaviour was the problem :)